# using left join with order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, left-join

hi guys am trying to display a particular set of data from by database using left join and i want it to be in alphabetical order so i introduced ORDER BY but i keep on getting a syntax error.

the query works perfect without the ORDER BY but i really need the result to be sorted alphabetically. here is my query:

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT s.StaffName, d.DeptName, b.age, b.telephone,b.email, b.address, t.position, t.salary FROM Staffs AS s\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN  Departments as d ON d.DepartmentID = s.DepartmentID\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN BioData AS b ON b.BioID = s.StaffID\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN StatusTable AS t ON t.ownerID = s.StaffID"
                + "ORDER BY s.StaffName";
```

and here is the error stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: near "BY": syntax error
at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:115)
at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)
at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
at HR.StaffList.retrvStaffList(StaffList.java:249)
at HR.StaffList.<init>(StaffList.java:37)
at HR.MainPage.listStaffMenuActionPerformed(MainPage.java:3085)
at HR.MainPage.access$3800(MainPage.java:45)
at HR.MainPage$42.actionPerformed(MainPage.java:1453)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

i have checked other left Join with ORDER BY questions in this forum but i still can't spot what is wrong.

pls guys i need help with this...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a space or a newline before your `ORDER BY` or after the `s.StaffID` on the previous line.

As it is now, after concatenation, the end of your query reads as:

```
LEFT JOIN StatusTable AS t ON t.ownerID = s.StaffIDORDER BY s.StaffName
                                                  ^^
```

This causes an `SQLException` to be thrown because SQLite can't make sense of the freestanding `BY` keyword.

Comment: wow! thanks! didn't even notice that. but there is another problem...the ORDER BY didn't arrange the names in alphabetical order. i discovered two names were out of place. please am i using the right query?